# (event.Target === document.getElementById("id")) returns false even though they are pointing at the same element

Tags: javascript, html

guys! First time here and thanks for reading in advance.

I have generated some elements dynamically and used event binding to add events to them as shown below.

```
for(var i = 0, length = list.length || 0; i < length; i++){
    str += "<li class = 'mb-2' data-reply_id ='" + list[i].reply_id + "'>";
    str += "<div><div class = 'width100 reply_info'><span><strong>" + list[i].replyer +"</strong></span>";
    str += "<span><small>" + replyService.formatDate(list[i].reply_date) + "</small></span>";
    str += "<button class = 'basic_btn btn btn-primary' id = 'reply_modify'>modify</button><button class = 'basic_btn btn btn-primary' id = 'reply_delete'>delete</button></div>";
    str += "<div class='comment-content comment col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-12 width100'><p class = 'fn'>";
    str += list[i].reply + "</p></div></div></li>";
}
replyUL.html(str);

$("#comments").on("click", "li", function(e){
    var reply_idValue = $(this).data("reply_id");

    console.log(reply_idValue);
    console.log(e.target);    
    console.log(typeof(e.target));
    console.log("");
    console.log(document.getElementById("reply_delete"));
    console.log(typeof(document.getElementById("reply_delete")));   

    if(e.target === document.getElementById("reply_delete")){
        console.log("worked!");
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            replyService.remove(reply_idValue, function(result){
            alert(result);
            showList(1);
            })
        }else{
            console.log("not working!");
    }
```

But the problem is, (e.target === document.getElementById("reply_delete")) returns false,
even though console.log(e.target); and console.log(document.getElementById("reply_delete")); are returning the same button element(and of course the same type, too).

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you create multiple elements with the same id. Don't do that - **id must be unique**. I would suggest to use classes instead:

```
<button class='basic_btn btn btn-primary reply_delete'>
```

And then you could write: `if (e.target.classList.contains('reply_delete')) { ... }`

References: [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id), [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)